# Problem generating manifest. Could not load assembly Microsoft.Windows.SDK.Contracts when installing nuget Microsoft.Toolkit.Forms.UI.Controls.Webview

Tags: visual-studio, winforms, nuget, package-managers

I'm getting the following errors after installing the nuget package Microsoft.Toolkit.Forms.UI.Controls.Webview:

> Severity Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error       Problem generating manifest. Could not load file or assembly 'C:\Users\Vladimir.nuget\packages\microsoft.windows.sdk.contracts\10.0.18362.2005\ref\netstandard2.0\Windows.Media.MediaControlContract.winmd' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.    OutlookAddIn
>   Error       Problem generating manifest. Could not load file or assembly 'C:\Users\Vladimir.nuget\packages\microsoft.windows.sdk.contracts\10.0.18362.2005\ref\netstandard2.0\Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation.ActivationCameraSettingsContract.winmd' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.  OutlookAddIn
>   Error       Problem generating manifest. Could not load file or assembly 'C:\Users\Vladimir.nuget\packages\microsoft.windows.sdk.contracts\10.0.18362.2005\ref\netstandard2.0\Windows.Perception.Automation.Core.PerceptionAutomationCoreContract.winmd' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.   OutlookAddIn
>   Error       Problem generating manifest. Could not load file or assembly 'C:\Users\Vladimir.nuget\packages\microsoft.windows.sdk.contracts\10.0.18362.2005\ref\netstandard2.0\Windows.ApplicationModel.Preview.Notes.PreviewNotesContract.winmd' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.   OutlookAddIn
>   Error       Problem generating manifest. Could not load file or assembly 'C:\Users\Vladimir.nuget\packages\microsoft.windows.sdk.contracts\10.0.18362.2005\ref\netstandard2.0\Windows.Web.Http.Diagnostics.HttpDiagnosticsContract.winmd' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.  OutlookAddIn
>   Error       Problem generating manifest. Could not load file or assembly 'C:\Users\Vladimir.nuget\packages\microsoft.windows.sdk.contracts\10.0.18362.2005\ref\netstandard2.0\Windows.Devices.DevicesLowLevelContract.winmd' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.   OutlookAddIn
>   Error       Problem generating manifest. Could not load file or assembly 'C:\Users\Vladimir.nuget\packages\microsoft.windows.sdk.contracts\10.0.18362.2005\ref\netstandard2.0\Windows.Devices.Scanners.ScannerDeviceContract.winmd' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.    OutlookAddIn
>   Error       Problem generating manifest. Could not load file or assembly 'C:\Users\Vladimir.nuget\packages\microsoft.windows.sdk.contracts\10.0.18362.2005\ref\netstandard2.0\Windows.UI.Xaml.Hosting.HostingContract.winmd' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.   OutlookAddIn
>   Error       Problem generating manifest. Could not load file or assembly 'C:\Users\Vladimir.nuget\packages\microsoft.windows.sdk.contracts\10.0.18362.2005\ref\netstandard2.0\Windows.Media.AppRecording.AppRecordingContract.winmd' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.   OutlookAddIn
>   Error       Problem generating manifest. Could not load file or assembly 'C:\Users\Vladimir.nuget\packages\microsoft.windows.sdk.contracts\10.0.18362.2005\ref\netstandard2.0\Windows.Management.Deployment.Preview.DeploymentPreviewContract.winmd' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.   OutlookAddIn
>   Error       Problem generating manifest. Could not load file or assembly 'C:\Users\Vladimir.nuget\packages\microsoft.windows.sdk.contracts\10.0.18362.2005\ref\netstandard2.0\Windows.Devices.Printers.Extensions.ExtensionsContract.winmd' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.    OutlookAddIn
>   Error       Problem generating manifest. Could not load file or assembly 'C:\Users\Vladimir.nuget\packages\microsoft.windows.sdk.contracts\10.0.18362.2005\ref\netstandard2.0\Windows.Gaming.XboxLive.StorageApiContract.winmd' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.    OutlookAddIn
>   Error       Problem generating manifest. Could not load file or assembly 'C:\Users\Vladimir.nuget\packages\microsoft.windows.sdk.contracts\10.0.18362.2005\ref\netstandard2.0\Windows.Networking.NetworkOperators.NetworkOperatorsFdnContract.WinMD' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.   OutlookAddIn
>   Error       Problem generating manifest. Could not load file or assembly 'C:\Users\Vladimir.nuget\packages\microsoft.windows.sdk.contracts\10.0.18362.2005\ref\netstandard2.0\Windows.Gaming.UI.GamingUIProviderContract.winmd' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.    OutlookAddIn
>   Error       Problem generating manifest. Could not load file or assembly 'C:\Users\Vladimir.nuget\packages\microsoft.windows.sdk.contracts\10.0.18362.2005\ref\netstandard2.0\Windows.Graphics.Printing3D.Printing3DContract.winmd' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.    OutlookAddIn
>   Error       Problem generating manifest. Could not load file or assembly 'C:\Users\Vladimir.nuget\packages\microsoft.windows.sdk.contracts\10.0.18362.2005\ref\netstandard2.0\Windows.ApplicationModel.StartupTaskContract.winmd' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.  OutlookAddIn
>   Error       Problem generating manifest. Could not load file or assembly 'C:\Users\Vladimir.nuget\packages\microsoft.windows.sdk.contracts\10.0.18362.2005\ref\netstandard2.0\Windows.UI.Core.AnimationMetrics.AnimationMetricsContract.winmd' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. OutlookAddIn
>   Error       Problem generating manifest. Could not load file or assembly 'C:\Users\Vladimir.nuget\packages\microsoft.windows.sdk.contracts\10.0.18362.2005\ref\netstandard2.0\Windows.System.SystemManagementContract.winmd' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.   OutlookAddIn
>   Error       Problem generating manifest. Could not load file or assembly 'C:\Users\Vladimir.nuget\packages\microsoft.windows.sdk.contracts\10.0.18362.2005\ref\netstandard2.0\Windows.Services.Maps.LocalSearchContract.winmd' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. OutlookAddIn
>   Error       Problem generating manifest. Could not load file or assembly 'C:\Users\Vladimir.nuget\packages\microsoft.windows.sdk.contracts\10.0.18362.2005\ref\netstandard2.0\Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation.WebUISearchActivatedEventsContract.winmd' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.    OutlookAddIn
>   Error       Problem generating manifest. Could not load file or assembly 'C:\Users\Vladimir.nuget\packages\microsoft.windows.sdk.contracts\10.0.18362.2005\ref\netstandard2.0\Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ViewManagementViewScalingContract.winmd' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.   OutlookAddIn
>   Error       Problem generating manifest. Could not load file or assembly 'C:\Users\Vladimir.nuget\packages\microsoft.windows.sdk.contracts\10.0.18362.2005\ref\netstandard2.0\Windows.Networking.Connectivity.WwanContract.winmd' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.  OutlookAddIn
>   Error       Problem generating manifest. Could not load file or assembly 'C:\Users\Vladimir.nuget\packages\microsoft.windows.sdk.contracts\10.0.18362.2005\ref\netstandard2.0\Windows.Media.AppBroadcasting.AppBroadcastingContract.winmd' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. OutlookAddIn
>   Error       Problem generating manifest. Could not load file or assembly 'C:\Users\Vladimir.nuget\packages\microsoft.windows.sdk.contracts\10.0.18362.2005\ref\netstandard2.0\Windows.Globalization.GlobalizationJapanesePhoneticAnalyzerContract.winmd' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.   OutlookAddIn
>   Error       Problem generating manifest. Could not load file or assembly 'C:\Users\Vladimir.nuget\packages\microsoft.windows.sdk.contracts\10.0.18362.2005\ref\netstandard2.0\Windows.Services.Maps.GuidanceContract.winmd' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.    OutlookAddIn
>   Error       Problem generating manifest. Could not load file or assembly 'C:\Users\Vladimir.nuget\packages\microsoft.windows.sdk.contracts\10.0.18362.2005\ref\netstandard2.0\Windows.Security.ExchangeActiveSyncProvisioning.EasContract.winmd' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.   OutlookAddIn
>   Error       Problem generating manifest. Could not load file or assembly 'C:\Users\Vladimir.nuget\packages\microsoft.windows.sdk.contracts\10.0.18362.2005\ref\netstandard2.0\Windows.System.Profile.SystemManufacturers.SystemManufacturersContract.winmd' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.    OutlookAddIn
>   Error       Problem generating manifest. Could not load file or assembly 'C:\Users\Vladimir.nuget\packages\microsoft.windows.sdk.contracts\10.0.18362.2005\ref\netstandard2.0\Windows.UI.WebUI.Core.WebUICommandBarContract.winmd' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. OutlookAddIn
>   Error       Problem generating manifest. Could not load file or assembly 'C:\Users\Vladimir.nuget\packages\microsoft.windows.sdk.contracts\10.0.18362.2005\ref\netstandard2.0\Windows.Media.Capture.CameraCaptureUIContract.winmd' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. OutlookAddIn
>   Error       Problem generating manifest. Could not load file or assembly 'C:\Users\Vladimir.nuget\packages\microsoft.windows.sdk.contracts\10.0.18362.2005\ref\netstandard2.0\Windows.Phone.StartScreen.DualSimTileContract.WinMD' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. OutlookAddIn
>   Error       Problem generating manifest. Could not load file or assembly 'C:\Users\Vladimir.nuget\packages\microsoft.windows.sdk.contracts\10.0.18362.2005\ref\netstandard2.0\Windows.Media.Devices.CallControlContract.winmd' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. OutlookAddIn
>   Error       Problem generating manifest. Could not load file or assembly 'C:\Users\Vladimir.nuget\packages\microsoft.windows.sdk.contracts\10.0.18362.2005\ref\netstandard2.0\Windows.Phone.PhoneContract.winmd' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.   OutlookAddIn
>   Error       Problem generating manifest. Could not load file or assembly 'C:\Users\Vladimir.nuget\packages\microsoft.windows.sdk.contracts\10.0.18362.2005\ref\netstandard2.0\Windows.ApplicationModel.Calls.LockScreenCallContract.winmd' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. OutlookAddIn
>   Error       Problem generating manifest. Could not load file or assembly 'C:\Users\Vladimir.nuget\packages\microsoft.windows.sdk.contracts\10.0.18362.2005\ref\netstandard2.0\Windows.Gaming.Preview.GamesEnumerationContract.winmd' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.   OutlookAddIn
>   Error       Problem generating manifest. Could not load file or assembly 'C:\Users\Vladimir.nuget\packages\microsoft.windows.sdk.contracts\10.0.18362.2005\ref\netstandard2.0\Windows.System.UserProfile.UserProfileLockScreenContract.winmd' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.  OutlookAddIn
>   Error       Problem generating manifest. Could not load file or assembly 'C:\Users\Vladimir.nuget\packages\microsoft.windows.sdk.contracts\10.0.18362.2005\ref\netstandard2.0\Windows.AI.MachineLearning.Preview.MachineLearningPreviewContract.winmd' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. OutlookAddIn
>   Error       Problem generating manifest. Could not load file or assembly 'C:\Users\Vladimir.nuget\packages\microsoft.windows.sdk.contracts\10.0.18362.2005\ref\netstandard2.0\Windows.ApplicationModel.Calls.CallsVoipContract.winmd' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.  OutlookAddIn
>   Error       Problem generating manifest. Could not load file or assembly 'C:\Users\Vladimir.nuget\packages\microsoft.windows.sdk.contracts\10.0.18362.2005\ref\netstandard2.0\Windows.ApplicationModel.Calls.CallsPhoneContract.winmd' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. OutlookAddIn
>   Error       Problem generating manifest. Could not load file or assembly 'C:\Users\Vladimir.nuget\packages\microsoft.windows.sdk.contracts\10.0.18362.2005\ref\netstandard2.0\Windows.Storage.Provider.CloudFilesContract.winmd' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.   OutlookAddIn
>   Error       Problem generating manifest. Could not load file or assembly 'C:\Users\Vladimir.nuget\packages\microsoft.windows.sdk.contracts\10.0.18362.2005\ref\netstandard2.0\Windows.ApplicationModel.CommunicationBlocking.CommunicationBlockingContract.winmd' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.  OutlookAddIn
>   Error       Problem generating manifest. Could not load file or assembly 'C:\Users\Vladimir.nuget\packages\microsoft.windows.sdk.contracts\10.0.18362.2005\ref\netstandard2.0\Windows.Media.Capture.AppCaptureMetadataContract.winmd' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.  OutlookAddIn
>   Error       Problem generating manifest. Could not load file or assembly 'C:\Users\Vladimir.nuget\packages\microsoft.windows.sdk.contracts\10.0.18362.2005\ref\netstandard2.0\Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract.winmd' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.   OutlookAddIn
>   Error       Problem generating manifest. Could not load file or assembly 'C:\Users\Vladimir.nuget\packages\microsoft.windows.sdk.contracts\10.0.18362.2005\ref\netstandard2.0\Windows.UI.Shell.SecurityAppManagerContract.winmd' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.   OutlookAddIn
>   Error       Problem generating manifest. Could not load file or assembly 'C:\Users\Vladimir.nuget\packages\microsoft.windows.sdk.contracts\10.0.18362.2005\ref\netstandard2.0\Windows.ApplicationModel.Wallet.WalletContract.winmd' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.    OutlookAddIn
>   Error       Problem generating manifest. Could not load file or assembly 'C:\Users\Vladimir.nuget\packages\microsoft.windows.sdk.contracts\10.0.18362.2005\ref\netstandard2.0\Windows.Devices.SmartCards.SmartCardBackgroundTriggerContract.winmd' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. OutlookAddIn
>   Error       Problem generating manifest. Could not load file or assembly 'C:\Users\Vladimir.nuget\packages\microsoft.windows.sdk.contracts\10.0.18362.2005\ref\netstandard2.0\Windows.Gaming.UI.GameChatOverlayContract.winmd' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. OutlookAddIn
>   Error       Problem generating manifest. Could not load file or assembly 'C:\Users\Vladimir.nuget\packages\microsoft.windows.sdk.contracts\10.0.18362.2005\ref\netstandard2.0\Windows.Media.Capture.GameBarContract.winmd' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. OutlookAddIn
>   Error       Problem generating manifest. Could not load file or assembly 'C:\Users\Vladimir.nuget\packages\microsoft.windows.sdk.contracts\10.0.18362.2005\ref\netstandard2.0\Windows.AI.MachineLearning.MachineLearningContract.winmd' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.    OutlookAddIn
>   Error       Problem generating manifest. Could not load file or assembly 'C:\Users\Vladimir.nuget\packages\microsoft.windows.sdk.contracts\10.0.18362.2005\ref\netstandard2.0\Windows.System.Profile.ProfileHardwareTokenContract.winmd' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.   OutlookAddIn
>   Error       Problem generating manifest. Could not load file or assembly 'C:\Users\Vladimir.nuget\packages\microsoft.windows.sdk.contracts\10.0.18362.2005\ref\netstandard2.0\Windows.Devices.Sms.LegacySmsApiContract.winmd' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.  OutlookAddIn
>   Error       Problem generating manifest. Could not load file or assembly 'C:\Users\Vladimir.nuget\packages\microsoft.windows.sdk.contracts\10.0.18362.2005\ref\netstandard2.0\Windows.ApplicationModel.Preview.InkWorkspace.PreviewInkWorkspaceContract.winmd' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. OutlookAddIn
>   Error       Problem generating manifest. Could not load file or assembly 'C:\Users\Vladimir.nuget\packages\microsoft.windows.sdk.contracts\10.0.18362.2005\ref\netstandard2.0\Windows.Networking.XboxLive.XboxLiveSecureSocketsContract.winmd' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. OutlookAddIn
>   Error       Problem generating manifest. Could not load file or assembly 'C:\Users\Vladimir.nuget\packages\microsoft.windows.sdk.contracts\10.0.18362.2005\ref\netstandard2.0\Windows.Devices.Custom.CustomDeviceContract.winmd' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.   OutlookAddIn
>   Error       Problem generating manifest. Could not load file or assembly 'C:\Users\Vladimir.nuget\packages\microsoft.windows.sdk.contracts\10.0.18362.2005\ref\netstandard2.0\Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindowDialogsContract.winmd' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. OutlookAddIn
>   Error       Problem generating manifest. Could not load file or assembly 'C:\Users\Vladimir.nuget\packages\microsoft.windows.sdk.contracts\10.0.18362.2005\ref\netstandard2.0\Windows.UI.Xaml.Core.Direct.XamlDirectContract.winmd' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.    OutlookAddIn
>   Error       Problem generating manifest. Could not load file or assembly 'C:\Users\Vladimir.nuget\packages\microsoft.windows.sdk.contracts\10.0.18362.2005\ref\netstandard2.0\Windows.System.Profile.ProfileRetailInfoContract.winmd' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.  OutlookAddIn
>   Error       Problem generating manifest. Could not load file or assembly 'C:\Users\Vladimir.nuget\packages\microsoft.windows.sdk.contracts\10.0.18362.2005\ref\netstandard2.0\Windows.Embedded.DeviceLockdown.DeviceLockdownContract.winmd' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.    OutlookAddIn
>   Error       Problem generating manifest. Could not load file or assembly 'C:\Users\Vladimir.nuget\packages\microsoft.windows.sdk.contracts\10.0.18362.2005\ref\netstandard2.0\Windows.System.UserProfile.UserProfileContract.winmd' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.    OutlookAddIn
>   Error       Problem generating manifest. Could not load file or assembly 'C:\Users\Vladimir.nuget\packages\microsoft.windows.sdk.contracts\10.0.18362.2005\ref\netstandard2.0\Windows.Media.Capture.AppBroadcastContract.winmd' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.    OutlookAddIn
>   Error       Problem generating manifest. Could not load file or assembly 'C:\Users\Vladimir.nuget\packages\microsoft.windows.sdk.contracts\10.0.18362.2005\ref\netstandard2.0\Windows.UI.ApplicationSettings.ApplicationsSettingsContract.winmd' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.   OutlookAddIn
>   Error       Problem generating manifest. Could not load file or assembly 'C:\Users\Vladimir.nuget\packages\microsoft.windows.sdk.contracts\10.0.18362.2005\ref\netstandard2.0\Windows.Devices.SmartCards.SmartCardEmulatorContract.winmd' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.  OutlookAddIn
>   Error       Problem generating manifest. Could not load file or assembly 'C:\Users\Vladimir.nuget\packages\microsoft.windows.sdk.contracts\10.0.18362.2005\ref\netstandard2.0\Windows.ApplicationModel.FullTrustAppContract.winmd' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. OutlookAddIn
>   Error       Problem generating manifest. Could not load file or assembly 'C:\Users\Vladimir.nuget\packages\microsoft.windows.sdk.contracts\10.0.18362.2005\ref\netstandard2.0\Windows.ApplicationModel.Search.Core.SearchCoreContract.winmd' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.   OutlookAddIn
>   Error       Problem generating manifest. Could not load file or assembly 'C:\Users\Vladimir.nuget\packages\microsoft.windows.sdk.contracts\10.0.18362.2005\ref\netstandard2.0\Windows.WinMD' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.   OutlookAddIn
>   Error       Problem generating manifest. Could not load file or assembly 'C:\Users\Vladimir.nuget\packages\microsoft.windows.sdk.contracts\10.0.18362.2005\ref\netstandard2.0\Windows.System.Profile.ProfileSharedModeContract.winmd' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.  OutlookAddIn
>   Error       Problem generating manifest. Could not load file or assembly 'C:\Users\Vladimir.nuget\packages\microsoft.windows.sdk.contracts\10.0.18362.2005\ref\netstandard2.0\Windows.ApplicationModel.Background.BackgroundAlarmApplicationContract.winmd' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.    OutlookAddIn
>   Error       Problem generating manifest. Could not load file or assembly 'C:\Users\Vladimir.nuget\packages\microsoft.windows.sdk.contracts\10.0.18362.2005\ref\netstandard2.0\Windows.ApplicationModel.Search.SearchContract.winmd' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.    OutlookAddIn
>   Error       Problem generating manifest. Could not load file or assembly 'C:\Users\Vladimir.nuget\packages\microsoft.windows.sdk.contracts\10.0.18362.2005\ref\netstandard2.0\Windows.Networking.NetworkOperators.LegacyNetworkOperatorsContract.winmd' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.    OutlookAddIn
>   Error       Problem generating manifest. Could not load file or assembly 'C:\Users\Vladimir.nuget\packages\microsoft.windows.sdk.contracts\10.0.18362.2005\ref\netstandard2.0\Windows.Gaming.Input.GamingInputPreviewContract.winmd' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.   OutlookAddIn
>   Error       Problem generating manifest. Could not load file or assembly 'C:\Users\Vladimir.nuget\packages\microsoft.windows.sdk.contracts\10.0.18362.2005\ref\netstandard2.0\Windows.Media.Protection.ProtectionRenewalContract.winmd' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.    OutlookAddIn
>   Error       Problem generating manifest. Could not load file or assembly 'C:\Users\Vladimir.nuget\packages\microsoft.windows.sdk.contracts\10.0.18362.2005\ref\netstandard2.0\Windows.Security.EnterpriseData.EnterpriseDataContract.winmd' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.    OutlookAddIn
>   Error       Problem generating manifest. Could not load file or assembly 'C:\Users\Vladimir.nuget\packages\microsoft.windows.sdk.contracts\10.0.18362.2005\ref\netstandard2.0\Windows.ApplicationModel.Calls.Background.CallsBackgroundContract.winmd' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. OutlookAddIn
>   Error       Problem generating manifest. Could not load file or assembly 'C:\Users\Vladimir.nuget\packages\microsoft.windows.sdk.contracts\10.0.18362.2005\ref\netstandard2.0\Windows.Networking.Sockets.ControlChannelTriggerContract.winmd' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.  OutlookAddIn
>   Error       Problem generating manifest. Could not load file or assembly 'C:\Users\Vladimir.nuget\packages\microsoft.windows.sdk.contracts\10.0.18362.2005\ref\netstandard2.0\Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation.ActivatedEventsContract.winmd' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.   OutlookAddIn
>   Error       Problem generating manifest. Could not load file or assembly 'C:\Users\Vladimir.nuget\packages\microsoft.windows.sdk.contracts\10.0.18362.2005\ref\netstandard2.0\Windows.ApplicationModel.SocialInfo.SocialInfoContract.winmd' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.    OutlookAddIn
>   Error       Problem generating manifest. Could not load file or assembly 'C:\Users\Vladimir.nuget\packages\microsoft.windows.sdk.contracts\10.0.18362.2005\ref\netstandard2.0\Windows.Management.Workplace.WorkplaceSettingsContract.winmd' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.    OutlookAddIn
>   Error       Problem generating manifest. Could not load file or assembly 'C:\Users\Vladimir.nuget\packages\microsoft.windows.sdk.contracts\10.0.18362.2005\ref\netstandard2.0\Windows.ApplicationModel.Resources.Management.ResourceIndexerContract.winmd' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. OutlookAddIn
>   Error       Problem generating manifest. Could not load file or assembly 'C:\Users\Vladimir.nuget\packages\microsoft.windows.sdk.contracts\10.0.18362.2005\ref\netstandard2.0\Windows.Devices.Portable.PortableDeviceContract.winmd' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.   OutlookAddIn
>   Error       Problem generating manifest. Could not load file or assembly 'C:\Users\Vladimir.nuget\packages\microsoft.windows.sdk.contracts\10.0.18362.2005\ref\netstandard2.0\Windows.Media.Playlists.PlaylistsContract.winmd' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. OutlookAddIn
>   Error       Problem generating manifest. Could not load file or assembly 'C:\Users\Vladimir.nuget\packages\microsoft.windows.sdk.contracts\10.0.18362.2005\ref\netstandard2.0\Windows.Media.Capture.AppCaptureContract.winmd' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.  OutlookAddIn
>   Error       Problem generating manifest. Could not load file or assembly 'C:\Users\Vladimir.nuget\packages\microsoft.windows.sdk.contracts\10.0.18362.2005\ref\netstandard2.0\Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation.ContactActivatedEventsContract.winmd' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.    OutlookAddIn
>   Error       Problem generating manifest. Could not load file or assembly 'C:\Users\Vladimir.nuget\packages\microsoft.windows.sdk.contracts\10.0.18362.2005\ref\netstandard2.0\Windows.Services.TargetedContent.TargetedContentContract.winmd' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.  OutlookAddIn
>   Error       Problem generating manifest. Could not load file or assembly 'C:\Users\Vladimir.nuget\packages\microsoft.windows.sdk.contracts\10.0.18362.2005\ref\netstandard2.0\Windows.Services.Store.StoreContract.winmd' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.  OutlookAddIn
>   Error       Problem generating manifest. Could not load file or assembly 'C:\Users\Vladimir.nuget\packages\microsoft.windows.sdk.contracts\10.0.18362.2005\ref\netstandard2.0\Windows.Devices.Printers.PrintersContract.winmd' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. OutlookAddIn
>   Error       Problem generating manifest. Could not load file or assembly 'C:\Users\Vladimir.nuget\packages\microsoft.windows.sdk.contracts\10.0.18362.2005\ref\netstandard2.0\Windows.Foundation.FoundationContract.winmd' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. OutlookAddIn

Here's what I have done:

1. Switch to PackageReference as default. Tools -> Options -> Nuget Package Manager -> General -> Default to PackageReference.
2. Migrated nuget packages to PackageReference. Right-click reference and selected migrate to packagereference.
3. Installed nuget for Microsoft `Microsoft.Toolkit.Forms.UI.Controls.Webview`. I was initially getting the error regarding PackageReference but the previous steps fixed it.
4. I'm now getting the errors above, and they're all related to the Contracts nuget. I've installed and uninstalled this nuget with no results.

Comment: I wonder if you're having a 32-bit / 64-bit conflict: a 32bit project references a x64 dll. If so,please check your project by right-click project-->Properties-->Build-->set `Target platform` to `Any CPU`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been in contact with the owners of the SDK, and we've done some testing on this. It seems like if you're using a VSTO AddIn project, the SDK will throw these errors. Any other projects have worked fine. What I've done instead is create a form in a different project, and referenced the WebView form in my addin project. This workaround solved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm now getting the errors above, and they're all related to the
>   Contracts nuget. I've installed and uninstalled this nuget with no
>   results.

From your description, I created a wpf framework 4.7.2 project which references `microsoft.windows.sdk.contracts` with `packages.config` format in VS2019. After that, right-click the `packages.config`,migrate to packagereference,install `Microsoft.Toolkit.Forms.UI.Controls.Webview` without any errors. Quite strange. SO l sugget you could follow these steps to roubleshoot your issue:

**1)** perhaps you're having a 32-bit / 64-bit conflict. For an example, a `32bit` project references a `x64` dll. Please right-click on your project-->`Build`-->set `Platform target` to **Any CPU**. Also, uncheck `Prefer 32-bit`.

**2)** add these codes in `xxxx.csproj` file

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
  <GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType>true</GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType>
</PropertyGroup>
```

**3)** set `Platform target` to **Any CPU** then click `Tools`-->`Nuget Package Manager`--> `Package Manager Console`-->input `update-Package -reinstall`

Comment: I was having `unresolved type declaration [context]: Windows.Storage.Provider.IStorageProviderItemPropertySource` and running a `nuget.exe update CloudMirror\CloudMirror.sln` solved it for me. The Nuget inside VS is broken though.